# Why is this AJAX/POST taking precedence over the entire block of code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I am sorry, but I cannot for the life of me figure this out.

```
function submit_order_form() {

    if (typeof storedFiles !== 'undefined') {

            jQuery('.overlay-loading').css('visibility', 'visible')
            return false;
            var formData = new FormData();
            for (var key in storedFiles) {
                    formData.append(key, storedFiles[key]);
            }
            formData.append("rep", $('#sales_rep').val() );
            $.ajax({
                    url: '/send_invoice.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: formData,
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    async: false,
                    success: function (response) {
                            jQuery('#new_files_ajax').empty();
                            jQuery('#new_files_ajax').text(response.message);
                            jQuery('.overlay-loading').css('visibility', 'hidden')

                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                            jQuery('.overlay-loading').css('visibility', 'hidden')
                            console.log(error);
                    }
            });
    }
```

}

I want the

```
            jQuery('.overlay-loading').css('visibility', 'visible')
```

to run before the ajax call, which it does not, the ajax call just goes through fine but that visibility css change never happens until right at the end for 1 second and then goes back again because its called in the success function. If I return false right before the ajax call it works as expected. What in the world am I missing here? Its not async it should be waiting for that visibility call to take place.

Completely stumped.

Comment: You NEED `async` to allow the function return before your ajax call finished, thus allowing the DOM manipulation to take effect before the success or error callback.

Comment: Tried it, just hangs and the entire function never completes. But thank you for your time and comment its appreciated

Comment: no code after `return false;` will run in that function - so your ajax never happens, so your overlay is never hidden

Comment: @bravo what I meant was during debugging I put the return false right above the ajax call, and the "visibility visible" call worked as expected. If I let the ajax call run, the "Visibility Visible" call never runs.

Comment: @donny90210 - I bet it does, it's just too quick to see - the point of stack overflow is not to post code that works as expected :p - is there any error in the browser developer tools?

Comment: oh, `async: false,` that's the problem, don't do that

Comment: @bravo it can't be to quick I had it upload a 100 meg video and it still never turned on (went visibile) and right at the end of the upload it quickly went visibile then invisibile again.

Comment: oh, `async: false,` that's the problem, don't do that - it's deprecated AND it freezes UI updates in most browsers - just don't do it, ever `it should be waiting for that visibility call to take place` - it does, but the UI isn't refreshed yet because the code is ALL synchronous - I think firefox *may* update the UI, but Chrum certainly does not

Comment: @bravo that fixed it, if you'd like to post an answer I'll accept it  (async:false)

Comment: no, that's alright, nobody uses `async:false` anymore

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance calling this function from a button embedded on your HTML markup page inside of the `<form>` tag? If so, you'll need to pass the `event` object to the function so you can call `event.preventDefault()` which will prevent the page from reloading on when the request goes through.

By default when a form is submitted, the browser will automatically refresh, so you're visibility toggle will never work properly since the page is reloaded so the overlay would be rendered back to it's original state of being invisible.

Also just as a side note with the `FormData` call, you can pass the `storedFiles` object into the constructor rather than looping through the keys of `storedFiles` and appending each property to the `FormData` you created as you're not renaming keys in the form data to pass to the API endpoint.

Answer (score -1):

I can't be sure because I don't have any other code, but you can see how this works.

```
function submit_order_form() {

    if (typeof storedFiles !== 'undefined') {

        jQuery('.overlay-loading').css('visibility', 'visible')
        
        setTimeout(function(){
            var formData = new FormData();
            for (var key in storedFiles) {
                    formData.append(key, storedFiles[key]);
            }
            formData.append("rep", $('#sales_rep').val() );
            $.ajax({
                    url: '/send_invoice.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: formData,
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    async: false,
                    success: function (response) {
                            jQuery('#new_files_ajax').empty();
                            jQuery('#new_files_ajax').text(response.message);
                            jQuery('.overlay-loading').css('visibility', 'hidden')

                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                            jQuery('.overlay-loading').css('visibility', 'hidden')
                            console.log(error);
                    }
            });
        }, 0);
        return false; // <=========
    }
}
```

Of course, this is temporary and in practice it is recommended to fix the entire code with asynchronous calls. (async: true)